# AlarmManager & BroadcastReceiver did not execute or in wrong interval times

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I tried the sample of AlarmManager,which in https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms

My MainActivity.java like this:

```
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BroadcastReciever.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    // call every 5mins
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 5L, alarmIntent);
```

My BroadcastReciever.java like this:

```
public class BroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("Execute time:" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }
}
```

I hope it output something like "Execute time:Thu Apr 14 17:33:45 GMT+09:00 2022" in every 5mins
I installed the app in my physical device and restart the app in my physical device.(device still connect to the PC with an USB cable.)Android studio catch these log below:

> 2022-04-14 17:33:45.009 13580-13580/? I/com.example.ss: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni

> 2022-04-14 17:33:45.050 13580-13580/? E/com.example.ss: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

> 2022-04-14 17:33:45.611 13580-13580/com.example.ss I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.

> 2022-04-14 17:33:45.671 13580-13580/com.example.ss I/System.out: Execute time:Thu Apr 14 17:33:45 GMT+09:00 2022

The first problem is that, it's not output in every 5mins.
The second problem is that, sometimes it was output something like these (not in every 5mins)

> 2022-04-14 11:56:09.145 ...

> 2022-04-14 11:56:09.150 ...

> 2022-04-14 11:56:09.154 ...

I need to make a app, which make a new logfile at 0:00 every day.so I try the alarmmanager & broadcastReciever.
I need to make sure the logfile only be created one time,(in second case may create three times I guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are dozens of similar questions on Stackoverflow. You really should search before you create a new question.

Basically, `setRepeating()` is inexact. In order to conserve battery power, Android will change the actual time the alarm triggers. You have no control over that. If you need exact timing, you should use something like `setExact()` instead. This is not a repeating alarm, so if you need a repeating alarm you should do something like this: when the alarm gets triggered, do whatever and then set the next alarm.

You wrote:

> I need to make a app, which make a new logfile at 0:00 every day.so I
> try the alarmmanager & broadcastReciever. I need to make sure the
> logfile only be created one time,(in second case may create three
> times I guess)

so you should schedule an alarm with `setExact()` for 00:00 of the following day. When that alarm triggers, rotate your logfiles and then set an alarm for 00:00 of the following day. This will ensure that your alarm goes off at the correct time and that it only triggers once per day.